# How to compile universal swift package dependencies with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

My software depends on a few all-Swift packages.
I would like to create a universal binary in order to support Intel and Apple Silicon. However, the packages don't seem to be compiled for all architectures. I tried the tip to specify the architectures directly (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667440) as shown in screenshot but to no avail. What am I overlooking?

[image: build settings]

Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33)

[image: my computer]

Comment: this is odd. It now seem to work. I am not sure what happened.

Comment: and then it happened again. Odd.